# Understanding the ERC20 transferFrom default implementation - why is it working?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I'm having trouble to understand where the allowance is checked in the "transferFrom" function - IMHO the allowed amount is deducted but never checked weather it is sufficient to allow the transactions - what am I getting wrong here?

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {

    balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);

    allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);

    balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);

    Transfer(from, to, tokens);

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Where did you found this "default" implementation? It is incorrect without prerequisites `require` that checks for availability of amount in `allowed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the contract by any chance contain the line `using SafeMath for uint256`? `SafeMath` checks the output of subtraction (`sub`) for underflow. Inside the `sub` function of `SafeMath`, when the output becomes less than 0, it throws.

That's how the balances and allowances are checked in this contract: whenever more than their balance is being deducted, `SafeMath`'s `sub` function will throw.